# How do you specify child execution name/ID for AWS Step Functions Distributed map?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

We are using the AWS Step Function distributed map. It creates a number of child executions for the map run. How do you specify the name/execution ID for these child executions? By default it is a random GUID.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the Execution Name for the child executions created by a Map Run. It will always be a UUID.

If this feature was available, it could be problematic, because the [Name for workflow executions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html#StepFunctions-StartExecution-request-name) with Standard Workflows `must be unique for your AWS account, region, and state machine for 90 days.` That is, the probability of unintended conflicts would be high for a feature like [Distributed Map](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-asl-use-map-state-distributed.html) that is designed to dynamically initiate thousands of parallel workflow executions.

That said, please share more in the comments on your need and how you would like such a feature to work. We will take that into consideration when looking at future enhancements.

Comment: Thanks Justin. In our case, it's helpful to have the name for workflow executions incorporate the ID of the entity we're processing for debugging. Some mechanism where we can easily look up the execution for a pertinent entity ID within a map run would be helpful.